# Disapproving Tags on a Photo is not working.

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

Facebook Timeline is a nice feature, but i think there is a flaw in **Timeline and Tagging** feature.

As I have on this feature and I can see here:

**Privacy Setting-->Timeline and Tagging**

```
     Review tags friends add to your own posts on Facebook is ON
```

Now whenever someone tags me in a photo, I get a notification (this is okay) to Approve it and redirects me to the **Activity Log**

#### BUT

even if I disapprove the tag, I get tagged on that Photo! and I continue receiving notifications related to the Photo.

**Current Solution:**

Go to the Tagged Photo

- Click on **Report/Remove tag** -then it again ask some questions.
- And also **unfollow post**

But is there any other way.

Comment: @Rishabh Thanks for editing and answer too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That feature only decides if the tagged post or picture is going to appear on your timeline or not. It does not remove your tag if you disapprove it.